# Code Igniter File Upload, Unable to upload pdf and doc, result no file uploaded without an error

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, codeigniter-3

I've use do upload for my image on first time, and thats worked fine.
Then i want to upgrade for upload a pdf,doc, and xls.
Image, and xls worked, there is the file in *upload_folder* , and the file worked to download.

The problem when i trying to upload a pdf and docs, the file isnt uploaded to *upload_folder*
this is my code :

**mimes.php**

```
'pdf'   =>  array('application/pdf', 'application/force-download', 'application/x-download', 'binary/octet-stream'),
```

**core.php for download file**

```
function download($src)
{
    $this->load->helper('download');
    force_download('uploads/'.$src, NULL);
}
```

**insert.php for upload file**

```
function insert(){
        
        $id_car_header  = $this->input->post('input_id_car_header');
        $keterangan     = $this->input->post('input_keterangan');
        $arsip = $_FILES["input_arsip"]['name'];
       
        if ($arsip ='')
        {}
        else
        {   
            $config ['allowed_types']   = 'jpg|jpeg|png|docx|pdf|xls';
            $arsip_generate =$_FILES["input_arsip"]['name'];
            $config ['upload_path']     = './uploads';
            $config['file_name'] = $arsip_generate;
                    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                //$this->upload->initialize($config);
                if (!$this->upload->do_upload('input_arsip')) 
                    {
                         //$this->upload->display_errors();
                       echo "Gambar Gagal DiUpload..!!";
                    } else{
                            $arsip = $this->upload->data('file_name');
                    }
        }

        $data = array
        (
            'id_car_header' => $id_car_header,
            'ket_arsip'    =>  $keterangan,
            'datas'        =>  $arsip
        );

        $check = $this->m_db->insertDataAll("tbl_car_arsip", $data);
        $this->checkInsert($check);     
    }
```

**my layout as form**

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url().'/insert/insertArsip'; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="hidden" name="input_id_car_header" value="<?= $carHeader['id_car_header']?>">
                           
                             <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">File/Foto </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                
                               <input type="file" name="input_arsip" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Keterangan </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">

                                <textarea name="input_keterangan" required="required" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Masukan Keterangan"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
                           
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save
                                </button>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
</form>
```

I have trying to change my mime.php, and initialize, and change the structure code but all of that not working

Can somebody tell me what i need to do to make my code work for upload pdf and docs?
thank you very much

Comment: please remove [SOLVED] from the title and create an answer with your findings: See 
[**Can I answer my own question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I have change it, maybe you have a difference way to solve.

Comment: Now, please put the working code as answer and explain what you have changed to make it work

Comment: oh yeah, i dont know if this is the better way to clear my question, thanks. now my code maybe can help other people that having some problem like me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why this works after shut my laptop off and change the code little bit, all file with big size can be uploaded and downloaded
ofc i change the code from some user at Stackoverflow that having problem like me, thanks for that

i thinks this one that make uploaded pdf worked, i change this line

```
   $config ['allowed_types']   = '*';
```

**this is the update for upload file, i only change this function**

```
$id_car_header  = $this->input->post('input_id_car_header');
        $keterangan     = $this->input->post('input_keterangan');
        $arsip = $_FILES["input_arsip"]['name'];
      
            $config ['allowed_types']   = '*';
            $arsip_generate =$_FILES["input_arsip"]['name'];
            $config ['upload_path']     = './uploads';
            $config['file_name'] = $arsip_generate;
            $config['max_size'] = 2000000;
            $config['max_width'] = 1500;
            $config['max_height'] = 1500;
            
                    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                    $this->upload->initialize($config, true);
                    //$this->upload->initialize($config);
                    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('input_arsip')) 
                        {
                            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
                            $this->upload->display_errors();
                             //$this->upload->display_errors() 
                            echo "Gambar Gagal DiUpload..!!";
                            var_dump($config);
                    } else{
                            
                            $arsip = $this->upload->data('file_name');
                            $data = array
                                (
                                    'id_car_header' => $id_car_header,
                                    'ket_arsip'    =>  $keterangan,
                                    'datas'        =>  $arsip
                                );
                    $check = $this->m_db->insertDataAll("tbl_car_arsip", $data);
                    $this->checkInsert($check); 
 
                    }
```